# checking if file exists in FileInfo[]

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am creating a Windows application in which on a button click it will check a folder specified in the .config file for '.SQL' files and if it has any files then the application will execute the SQL file in the specified DB.
So for checking the '.sql' file in a directory I used the below code:

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(path);
FileInfo[] sqlfiles = d.GetFiles("*.sql");
```

Now, I want to add an IF condition to check any such file exist, if not I want to place a warning message.
So could you please help me to find how to check whether any such '.sql' file exist in that directory using the above code?

Comment: Check `sqlFiles.Length`?

Comment: If `sqlfiles.Length` is 0 then doesn't that mean no files exist?

Comment: ```(!(sqlfiles.Length==0))``` this worked

Comment: `if(sqlfiles.Length >0)` you are on your way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.Any()` to check if any array, or list, or IEnumerable has items.  IMO it's a much clearer intent than `list.Count > 0`.

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(path);
FileInfo[] sqlfiles = d.GetFiles("*.sql");
if(sqlFiles.Any())
{
   // At least one .sql file exists
}
else
{
    // No sql files exist
}
```

(Cue arguments about iterators etc.)